# Unwanted SVG animation delay on load

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an SVG logo that is being animated with CSS. It should animate immediately upon page load, but it seems to have about a 3 sec delay. The page only contains a nav, the SVG, and some text underneath. I am using Materialize to format.

I have tried adding a negative and 0s animation delay and tried using the vendor prefix.

The SVG in the html

```
<svg id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
        <defs>
         <style>
            .st0 {
              fill: #c09e56
            }
          </style>
          <g id="lines">
           <path id="a" class="st0" fill="#c09e56" d="M13.45 14.21l.1 15.79 1-.01-.1-16.29z" />
           <path id="b" class="st0" fill="#c09e56" d="M16.37 12.72V27.5h1V12.21z" />
           <path id="c" class="st0" fill="#c09e56" d="M13.53 29.75l.02 1.12.11.13L36.5 11.79v-1.35z" />
           <path id="d" class="st0" fill="#c09e56" d="M13.6 33.68l.02 1.27.04.05L36.5 15.56V14.2z" />
            <path id="e" class="st0" fill="#c09e56" d="M21.18 23.68l-.6.8L36.5 36.5v-1.25z" />
            <path id="f" class="st0" fill="#c09e56" d="M21.59 27l-.59.8 15.5 12.12v-1.27z" />
          </g>
       </defs>
        <use xlink:href="#lines" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#c09e56" />
      </svg>
```

The CSS

```
svg{
  overflow:visible;
  fill: #C09E56;
  stroke: transparent;
  stroke-width: 0;
  width:200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
}

path {
  stroke: #C09E56;
  stroke-width: 0.5;
  stroke-dasharray: 100;
  stroke-dashoffset: -100;
  animation: draw 8s linear forwards;
  animation-delay: -0.30s!important;

}



@keyframes draw {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill:#C09E56;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just found it, the `stroke-dashoffset:-100` was causing the delay. Looks like it was making the path to drawing the line longer. 
Chris Coyier explains: https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/

Comment: I've also experienced this issue right now.
Thank you for providing your solution, I'd have never found it myself.